# Unity3d temperature simulation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dynamically-generated, perlin-noise

I'm writing a monster AI that has some aspects of group mentality for my game. My first question is what would be the best way to make a heatmap in unity for migration patterns and such. I can figure out lots of things on my own, but I would like some steering in the right direction.

Basically, I need a perlin-noise-esque map with hot/cold based on location and season that has fluctuations between different hot and cold zones over time. I don't know if there's a way to do this with just prelin noise, since all I've seen it do is random 2D maps. Any help would be appreciated.

Oh, and I prefer any code in c#, but it's not a necessity.

Comment: Can you clarify what the temperature should be based on? AI unit density? Season? If it is random, you can use 3D noise and use the 3rd axis as time so you get a smoothly changing value.

Comment: @AndrewGriffin I was going for seasons and location, maybe I'll add unit density later as a modifier to that, I'll update the question.